# GoogleTTS on Raspberry Pi won't say time and date

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm am using GoogleTTS on Raspberry Pi. My code will have GoogleTTS say out-loud normal text but not the current time or date. It will go through to shell the correct time and date. I have another voice called festival and if I replace GoogleTTS with festival --tts it will say the time and date. However I am trying to get it to work with GoogleTTS because the voice is better. Please help! Thanks!

Have tried:

voice.speak(os.system("date '+%I:%M %P'"))
voice.speak(os.system("date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y'"))

I have tried def os.system("date '+%I:%M %P'") and (os.system("date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y'") as time1 and date1. Then voice.speak(time1) and voice.speak(date1). It just gives me some werid audio output of signs such as %.

What I orginally tried:

```
import time
import os
import sys
from google_tts import GoogleTTS

voice = GoogleTTS()
voice.speak("Hello NAME. The time is.")
os.system("date '+%I:%M %P'")
os.system("date '+%I:%M %P' | GoogleTTS")
voice.speak("And the date is.")
os.system("date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y'")
os.system("date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y' | GoogleTTS")
```

When I tried def:

```
import time
import os
import sys
from google_tts import GoogleTTS

voice = GoogleTTS()
voice.speak("Hello NAME. The time is.")

def time1():
    os.system("date '+%I:%M %P'")

voice = GoogleTTS()
voice.speak(time1)

voice = GoogleTTS()
voice.speak("And the date is.")

def date1():
    os.system("date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y'")

voice = GoogleTTS()
voice.speak(date1)
```

This is the two voice thing that works:

```
import time
import os
import sys
from google_tts import GoogleTTS

voice = GoogleTTS()
voice.speak("Hello NAME. The time is.")
os.system("date '+%I:%M %P'")
os.system("date '+%I:%M %P' | festival --tts")
voice.speak("And the date is.")
os.system("date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y'")
os.system("date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y' | festival --tts")
```

For what I originally tried I got this:

06:06 pm
sh: 1: GoogleTTS: not found
Tuesday, 17, September, 2019
sh: 1: GoogleTTS: not found
date: write error: Broken pipe

For the def I got the same error:

And the two voice has no errors just shell text output:

06:07 pm
Tuesday, 17, September, 2019

Comment: Last code does not work now. I'm getting a error that says pipe_open: fork failed for the lines that use festival --tts

Answer (score 0):

The library been used here is receiving a string to convert to speech in the `speak` method.

`os.system` executes a command in a subshell and gives you no way to retrieve the text printed in the standard output.

However `subprocess` allows to retrieve text printed in `stdout` and bind that to a name.

```py
import subprocess

from google_tts import GoogleTTS

voice = GoogleTTS()
voice.speak("Hello NAME. The time is.")


completed_process = subprocess.run(
    "date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y'", shell=True, capture_output=True
)
date_today = completed_process.stdout.decode().strip()

voice.speak(date_today)
```

Comment: I ran your code and I got back an error that read. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/GoogleTTS-master/demo2.py", line 10, in <module>
    "date '+%A, %d, %B, %Y'", shell=True, capture_output=True
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 383, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'

Comment: `subprocess.run` was a recent addition in `python3.5`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module. You can achieve the same thing with older API like `subprocess.check_output` https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output